# How to replace snapshot: Jest and WebStorm 2019.1?

Tags: jestjs, webstorm

In window 'Run' of tests, I can open dialog for view difference. How I can replace old snapshot to new via IDE (in version WebStorm 2018, in there window is button for replace snapshot, but **version 2019.1** it's removed)?

I have button for view difference, but havn't button for replace snapshot:

[image]

Comment: The action is back in WebStorm 2019.1.2 (here's a related bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38326)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to 2019.1.2 solved my problem.